# How to make gallary view at bottom in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

The [nexGTv – Mobile TV for touch phone](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/screenshots/56307/?lang=en) app has a scrolling horizontal field manager that I want to create in my own app.
It has image buttons at the bottom of the screen, horizontally. These images slide to the right and to left.  The initial focus is the horizonal center image, then each image has 10 pixels of padding to the next image.  What should i use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can understand your question, but i can not give you related code but i can tell you the logic behind this. To do this you first set a image at center and set bottom padding 10 pixel then fill images left side and right side. You have to do this in paint method. If you are a Blackberry Developer then you can understand it and try to do it. All the work perform in paint method, by using loops you can do this. This work con not be done by Picture-Scroll-Field because you want middle image with extra padding.